# Java handling of Boolean and NULL

Tags: java, boolean

Boolean object in JAVA can have 3 values True, False, NULL

```
public class First {

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        System.out.println("equals(new Boolean(\"True\"),True) :: " + isEqual(new Boolean("True"), true));
        System.out.println("equals(new Boolean(\"False\"), new Boolean(null)) :: " + isEqual(new Boolean("False"), new Boolean(null)));
        System.out.println("equals(new Boolean(\"False\"), null)) :: " + isEqual(new Boolean("False"), null));
    }

    static boolean isEqual(Boolean a, Boolean b)
    {
        return a.equals(b);
    }
}
```

**Output for above code is**

```
equals(new Boolean("True"),True) :: true
equals(new Boolean("False"), new Boolean(null)) :: true
equals(new Boolean("False"), null)) :: false
```

Please explain why Case 2 returns true but Case 3 returns false

Comment: Obviously null cannot be equal to any valid, non-null reference.

Comment: How can be `null` equal to any other value ? and in second you are creating object `new Boolean(null)`

Comment: new Boolean(null) means a Boolean object created and its value is false.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's because the constructor for `Boolean`, if provided with `null` will allocate a Boolean object representing the value `false`

Read here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html

> public Boolean(String s)
>
> Allocates a Boolean object representing the value true if the string
>   argument is not null and is equal, ignoring case, to the string
>   "true". Otherwise, allocate a Boolean object representing the value
>   false. Examples: new Boolean("True") produces a Boolean object that
>   represents true. new Boolean("yes") produces a Boolean object that
>   represents false. Parameters:s - the string to be converted to a
>   Boolean.

Answer (score 4):

If you look at the source code of `Boolean`class, you can se that passing a `null`value returns `false`:

```
private static boolean toBoolean(String name) { 
    return ((name != null) && name.equalsIgnoreCase("true"));
 }
```

Comment: I don't know what version you were using then but in 1.8 there is `public static boolean parseBoolean(String s) {
        return ((s != null) && s.equalsIgnoreCase("true"));
    }`